# Lines in bibliography too long

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I have some lines in my bibliography that are printed too long while this is not the case for other long items. See the image for at the word International (item 77) [image]

How to solve this?

Latex code looks like

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none,urldate=comp,dateabbrev=false,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    urlseen = {retrieved},
}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]
```

and the item that is printed not correctly

```
@inproceedings{LevineKoltun:ICML2012,
    author = {Sergey Levine and Vladlen Koltun},
    title = {Continuous Inverse Optimal Control with Locally Optimal Examples},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 29th International Conference on Machine Learning},
    year = {2012},
    pages= {41--48}
}
```

Comment: Normally, `biblatex` quite happily hyphenates in bibliography entries. Something must be wrong with your setup. Can you provide a short yet concise [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the problem? I just checked with the snippets you posted and while I cannot reproduce the exact line width you have, in my example hyphenation worked fine.

Comment: Do you have any update for us. As I explained, this should actually work; without more to go on there is nothing we can do.

Comment: Now I use the pdflatex compiler instead of lualatex and it works fine now